# Apache Nifi processor QueryDatabaseTable, unexpected avro format

Tags: json, postgresql, apache-nifi, avro

I use NiFi processor `QueryDatabaseTable` which retrieves data from db (postgresql) and convert it to avro. The table in db has column `entries` with type `integer[]` and I expect that resulting avro will look like

```
{
     ...,
     entries: {11, 23, 33, 45},
     ...,
}
```

but I get the following:

```
{
    ...,
    entries: {bytes: {11, 23, 33, 45}},
    ...,
}
```

It is not that I except and It affects next steps of the pipeline. How to fix it?